# Returning just data from mysqli query

Tags: php

I am trying to receive data back from a mysql db but in my results I receive escape characters. How can I get rid of these and just return raw data (I'm a noob in this realm of coding so please keep that in mind)?

Here is a sample of my result (it's a json signature):

> {"signature":"\n\t\t\t[{\"lx\":16,\"ly\":16,\"mx\":16,\"my\":15},{\"lx\":16,\"ly\":17,\"mx\":16,\"my\":16},{\"lx\":16,\"ly\":18,\"mx\":16,\"my\":17},{\"lx\":16,\"ly\":20,\"mx\":16,\"my\":18},{\"lx\":16,\"ly\":21,\"mx\":16,\"my\":20},{\"lx\":16,\"ly\":22,\"mx\":16,\"my\":21},{\"lx\":16,\"ly\":25,\"mx\":16,\"my\":22},{\"lx\":16,\"ly\":26,\"mx\":16,\"my\":25},.....]\n\t\t\t"}

I would like to remove the: {"signature":"\n\t\t\t on the beginning and \n\t\t\t"} on the end automatically.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
<?php
{

    // Connect to MySQL
    $mysqli = new mysqli( 'localhost', 'root', 'rootpassword', 'crs' );

    //Check our connection_aborted
    if ($mysqli->connect_error ) {
        die( 'Connect Error: ' . $mysqli->connect_error );
    }

    //Read the signature
    $sql = "SELECT signature FROM rescue_forms WHERE id=53";
    $idresult = $mysqli->query($sql);


    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($idresults))
        $id = $row;

    //Just printing this so I can see the results.
    print json_encode($id);

    //sending this to a statement below.
    $json = json_encode($id);


    //Close connection
    $mysqli->close();
}

?>
```

Comment: use str_replace()

Comment: mysqli_fetch_assoc() returns an associative array containing all the selected fields of the record (even it it's just one field).  If you only want to json_encode the contents of the signature field, you'd want to do json_encode($id['signature']);

Comment: I see that adding  ['signature'] removed the field name, and that's great, but what about the other tags?

What this json represents is a signature in our database. There is a java script later in the code that looks to load this to regenerate that signature but the tags encasing the result are confusing the code.

Answer (score 0):

You are storing json in a database, which you shouldn't,
and for some reason you are encoding your json again, which is pointless.

Comment: Later in this code there is a snippet of java that looks to regenerate the signature that this json represents. That will probably be my next issue in this whole thing but for now getting the json without the tags surrounding it so that I can attempt to re-generate it is my main concern.

I guess I'll have to start looking into why this is a bad idea.

Comment: @YourCommonSense Perhaps it's tangential, but why shouldn't you store JSON in a database? I've seen Marco Pivetta (a.k.a. Ocramius, one of the core devs on Doctrine) say there's absolutely no problem storing JSON in MySQL (or PostgreSQL) as long as you recognise the limitations of doing so.

Comment: @Blowski well, there is json and json. When you know what are you doing and your database supports json type field, it's ok. But when you don't know even SQL, you should avoid storing the preformatted data.

Comment: @YourCommonSense I see, thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 0):

In a round about way of down voting my question and basically telling me I'm an idiot, it helped! (which is the point of the forum) In hopes that this might help someone else that might just be starting out coding this kind of thing. I was able to change my array around to get the raw data as I was expecting, here's my example:

```
<?php
{

    // Connect to MySQL
    $mysqli = new mysqli( 'localhost', 'root', 'rootpassword', 'crs' );

    //Check our connection_aborted
    if ($mysqli->connect_error ) {
        die( 'Connect Error: ' . $mysqli->connect_error );
    }

    //Read the signature
    $sql = "SELECT signature FROM rescue_forms WHERE id=53"; 
    $idresult = $mysqli->query($sql);

    while($sig=mysqli_fetch_assoc($idresult)){

        echo "<tr>";

        echo "<td>".$sig['signature']."</td>";

        echo "</tr>";

    }

    //Close connection
    $mysqli->close();
}

?>
```

Thank you to all that responded it was greatly appreciated! Also thank you @YourCommonSense for showing me the proper way to format my code in this window with your edit.